# Ran out of inodes because of something happening in the meteor packages folder

Tags: linux, centos, meteor

I'm running meteor in a centos server (not production) where I've installed meteor, this meteor app rebuilds everytime I pull the code from git. The server ran out of inodes and I've realised the problem is inside the `/root/.meteor/packages/` folder. I'm figuring out a way to solve this problem but I'd like to understand if I'm doing something wrong.

Total nr of inodes used for this folder is 700k, and the server's total is 900k, which shouldn't be reached.

It is possible that I might have killed the process and restarting meteor, I think this happened when I was updating and downgrading meteor's version (I had errors in the packages and decided to downgrade back), but would that explain why so many inodes are being used? Or could it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

Over time it seems to download a lot of different versions of the same packages and keeps them all, so just delete the packages folder and restart meteor so that it will download them again from scratch.